# Best LaTeX editor for Mac

Tags: editors, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

Hi,

I'm looking for a good LaTeX editor for mac.
Something like TeXnicCenter would be fine.

Comment: see [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides). TeXworks seems to be the most popular choice (apart from Emacs/Vim).

Comment: I'd suggest also TeXShop, to which TeXworks is inspired.

Comment: I would say that TeXShop is the most popular choice, not TeXWorks. TeXShop is a much more mature editing environment.

Comment: To test a distribution, TexShop is fine, then you can try TeXWorks but for me the best editor (> Vim and emacs) is TexMate. It's not free but you can try it during a month !

Comment: @Altermundus: TeXMate is missing from the linked list. Could you please add an entry.